# Angular child event targets wrong parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, eventemitter

I have some nested angular components that are giving me some problems with Event Emitters. The structure goes something like this:

```
<parent>
    <child-table id="table1">

    </child-table>
    <child-table id="table2">

    </child-table>
</parent>
```

Now the child-table component looks like this:

```
<toolbar (thingChanged)="onThingChanged($event)">
</toolbar>
```

and all onThingChanged() does is this:

```
@Output() thingChanged: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(); //at global level
@Input() thingValue: boolean; //also global

onThingChanged(changed: boolean)
    {
        this.thingChanged.emit(changed);
        this.populateTable();
    }
```

and toolbar's html looks like this:

```
<mat-slide-toggle id="thingValue"
        [(ngModel)]='thingValue' (ngModelChange)='onThingChanged($event)'>
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

What I see when this app runs is two tables with mat-slide toggles on both. However, for some reason, if I click on the toggle for the table on the right (in this case the one with id=table2), it always changes toggles the slider for the table on the left, table1.

The behavior I expect is that when I click on the toggle for table2, I see table2 call it's own populateTable() method, not table1's.

If anyone has any suggestions as to why this might be happening, I'd appreciate your help.

EDIT: Here's a stackblitz that reproduces the problem. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mhiihu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: would you be able to create a minimum reproducible version of your problem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy)? it seems you have not shared enough code to allow for the help you need...

Comment: The call in the html is missing a parameter: `<toolbar (thingChanged)="onThingChanged()">
</toolbar>` Is that just a typo in the question? Otherwise, this will emit `undefined` every time.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton yeah that's a typo, my bad. I'll fix that. Also I'm about to add a stackblitz; the styling isn't quite the same but it reproduces the problem

Comment: @TheAtomicPeter I can confirm Drenai's answer is correct, removing the id from the mat-slide-toggle fixes it. You need to make the id dynamic (like an input variable) so they aren't the same every time, or just don't include an id at all (it will be auto-generated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but if you have the exact same `id` on the toggle component could that be affecting it e.g. `<mat-slide-toggle id="thingValue"`

Maybe make this `id` dynamic

Comment: The stackblitz confirms this answer is correct. You can also not include an id and a unique one will be auto generated.

Comment: Guess that comment I thought I posted never actually posted. I meant to say, a while ago, Thanks for the help!